# how does this page do this?

Tags: jquery, scroll

How does this website achieve the scrolldown and than loading of the content?

I think it's amazing that the site gives you a scrolling down/up effect and that you're able to use the scrollbar to scroll ONLY the div  that is in view, and not the etire site.

http://imagemechanics.com.au

Comment: They load the content into divs and then move them around so that only 1 div is ever visible.

Comment: Please have a look at the code and post some specific part you do not understand ;)

Comment: @casper : that's the problem. when I click the scource code the content which is loaded in when a link is clicked isn't visible. I don't get it.

@pavium : English isn't my native language, so mistakes will be made. No need to point them out unless it makes the question I asked unable to be understood.

Comment: Aeonius : You can use a tool like firebug to see the source of dynamic content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loading of content after the div dropping down looks easy. You just `animate` the div in question into the required location and then fire an Ajax callback to load the content. I don't understand your point about the scrolling.

Comment: I edited the original question, maybe the scrolling part is motre clear now?

Comment: You could keep the header positioned absolutely so that only the new div would scroll.